# Populate input field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span on my page containing text, on page load, is it possible to populate an input field with this inner html using jQuery?

I've tried to setup a fiddle with my attempt only its not working...

http://jsfiddle.net/tQkaZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you tried is correct. you just forgot to add the dot[.] before class name

```
$('.hiddenfield').val(
    $('.prodheader').html()
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tQkaZ/5/

Answer (score 2):

You just missed the `.` off your first class selector. Here's an [updated working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQkaZ/1/).

```
$('hiddenfield').val( //Missing .
    $('.prodheader').html()
);​
```

Comment: @user766266 - No problem, it's easy to miss the obvious sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the class symbol in the selector. Here's the fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/tQkaZ/2/

```
$('.hiddenfield').val(
    $('.prodheader').html()
);​
```